# How to set SSIS project parameters from JAMS job?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to call an SSIS package from JAMS. I am able to to set the value of a variable from the JAMS using its parameter. Is it possible to set the project parameters in SSIS from JAMS job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Senior Support Engineer for MVP Systems Software, Inc. (the creators of JAMS).

After referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility:

**/Par[ameter]** [$Package:: | $Project:: | $ServerOption::] parameter_name [(data_type)]; literal_value: (Optional). Specifies parameter values. Multiple **/Parameter** options can be specified. The data types are CLR TypeCodes as strings. For a non-string parameter, the data type is specified in parenthesis, following the parameter name.

The **/Parameter** option can be used only with the **/ISServer** option.

You use the $Package, $Project, and $ServerOption prefixes to indicate a package parameter, project parameter, and a server option parameter, respectively. The default parameter type is package.

The following is an example of executing a package and providing myvalue for the project parameter (myparam) and the integer value 12 for the package parameter (anotherparam).

```
Dtexec /isserver “SSISDB\MyFolder\MyProject\MyPackage.dtsx” /server “.” /parameter $Project::myparam;myvalue /parameter anotherparam(int32);12
```

You can also set connection manager properties by using parameters. You use the CM prefix to denote a connection manager parameter.

In the following example, InitialCatalog property of the SourceServer connection manager is set to ssisdb.

```
/parameter CM.SourceServer.InitialCatalog;ssisdb
```

In the following example, ServerName property of the SourceServer connection manager is set to a period (.) to indicate the local server.

```
/parameter CM.SourceServer.ServerName;.
```

For Example:

```
/Par "$Project::ProjectParameter(Int32)";1
```